# Node, Express Multiple server cluster

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing, nodes

I'm a beginner development.
First. I'm not good at English, sorry to you..

I have a project, serve simple UI, and analysis system using node(react, front) and express(back).

I have two physical different servers(called A, B)

A is a main server, and B is a support A. If A has a problem(down, crash, etc), B is serving our application.

Now, I have a question. How can I use clustering for node on multiple physical servers?

Comment: You should read up on 'load-balancing', or 'nginx' (a commonly-used load-balancer).

Comment: You can have a look at 'Consul'+'Fabio'.

Comment: how can i tag your id;;?   btw thanks for you guys